# How to pass a property to DelegatingFilterProxy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my application, I needed to extend the DelegatingFilterProxy class to override the doFilter() method.

```
public class ExtendsDelegatingFilterProxy extends DelegatingFilterProxy {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain 
    filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // my code
    }
}
```

In the "my code" section, I need a property, which I try to read from a file via a @Configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class NameClass {
    @Value("${my.property}")
    private String myProperty;

    public String getMyProperty() {
       return myProperty;
    }
}
```

In the .properties file there is the property

```
my.property=https://localhost/example
```

I should point out that both the .properties file and the @Configuration class are used pervasively throughout the application and all properties are read correctly. Only the class inherited from DelegatingFilterProxy fails to read it. I assume this is due to the order in which things are set by Spring. Is there any way to solve it?